# Are "in" parameter modifiers considered a code smell?

Tags: c#, clean-code, functions, parameters

As of [C# 7.2+](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-parameter-modifier), you can add a parameter modifier `in` before the parameter type to define a parameter as const, essentially.

> It is like the ref or out keywords, except that in arguments cannot be modified by the called method. - [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-parameter-modifier)

Example from MSDN:

```
void InArgExample(in int number)
{
    number = 19; // error CS8331, it prevents modification of this parameter
}
```

Why is it useful? You can guarantee the caller that the argument passed will be unmodified as a result of calling that function. A promise in other words.

---

According to SOLID design principles and Clean Code by Robert Martin, is this considered a code smell along the same lines as `out` parameters?

**Sources:**

[Code Smell of the Week: Obsessed with Out Parameters](https://blogs.agilefaqs.com/2011/08/06/code-smell-of-week-obsessed-with-out-parameters/)

[What's wrong with output parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434402/whats-wrong-with-output-parameters)

Comment: Let us be clear... an `in` parameter is passed by reference. Usually C# prevents the modification of parameters passed into the method by making a copy, which is the default. Thus, the purpose of `in` is not to prevent the modification of parameters. If you want to allow the modification of the parameters, you opt out with `ref` (do not confuse with reference types). The purpose of `in` is to avoid the copy. Since no copy is done when using `in`, the constraint of not modifying the parameter has to be enforced by your code, the compiler checks that. Again, if you want to modify it, use `ref`.

Comment: Now, that I am talking about it, `out` is also a parameter passed by reference. And also allows the modification just like `ref`. Except it guarantees that the value will be initialized by the method, and the compiler checks that.

Comment: Note that SOLID are principles for class design and do not address parameter passing

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You've taken the line from MSDN out of context.

The most important part of the page is the first sentence: *"The `in` keyword causes arguments to be passed by reference."* It is primarily in this respect that the keyword is similar to `out` and `ref`.

This is important when you pass large `struct`s to functions. Passing them without a keyword is inefficient because the struct is copied. (No modifications should be visible outside.) Passing by reference is more efficient.

However, using the old `out` and `ref` keywords for this purpose it problematic. `out` is completely useless: it cannot be used to pass information into the function. `ref` is possible, but confusing: it allows the function to modify its parameter (with changes visible outside). This is unusual for structs. It is a likely source of bugs if you do it. And it's communicating the wrong intent if you don't intend to do it.

Hence the `in` keyword: a way to pass structs by reference without allowing them to be modified. And thus the sentence you quoted.

Using `in` to prevent modification of the parameter only (as in the MSDN example) instead of using it to improve efficiency **is** a code smell, by the way. Never pass `int`s as `in`. There's no point in preventing modifications of normal by-value parameters, as the modifications cannot be seen outside the function anyway. (This confuses some new programmers, but understanding by-value and by-reference is something they need to learn anyway.)

Answer (score 4):

No, using the keyword `in` to make an argument passed by reference to a method read only is not a code smell.

Modifying an input parameter is a side-effect. It can easily lead to code that is difficult to reason about and hard to change.

Bertrand Meyer’s command-query separation principle (CQS) states that a method should either be a command or a query.
If a method is a command, it mutates state (of it’s instance variables), but returns nothing (void).
If a method is a query, it has a return value, but does not mutate state.

If you follow this principle your code generally becomes easier to reason about and has less bugs. 
For example any method that returns a value can be safely called multiple times and it will always produce the same result.

Back to the `in` keyword. MSDN writes:

> Passing those arguments by reference avoids the (potentially)
>   expensive copy

By using the in keyword you signal the caller that the argument will be passed to the method as a reference, yet it’s safe to do, because it won’t be changed.

As a sidenote, I would advise that when you use `in` in the method signature, also specify it in the caller. It shows the intent and when there's an overload without `in`, that method will be chosen first.

Comment: Your last paragraph makes no sense. This is already the case for normal by-value parameters. Even if the function makes changes, they aren't visible outside.

Comment: Editted my answer @SebastianRedl

Answer (score 1):

While the words “in” and “out” relates to each other, I think they are quite different in this case. While the `out` keyword provides an alternative way of returning output, the `in` parameter seems more like a way of adding “read only” to the input parameter. Whether or not this is important to the caller, I can’t really decide on. I think it should be clear from the naming anyway.

Answer (score -5):

Its too new to make a call.

To be a code smell the snippet has to be indicative of a common bad design. With a new language feature there hasnt been time for people to abuse it enough yet.

I can see your point though. If you define an interface which limits the implementation this way does it imply that all your other old style methods *do* modify their parameters? Are side effects common in the rest of your code?

However, I can see in a few years everyone using `in` as standard. Not doing so might be the code smell.